Error in Exporting Database in phpmyadmin
Error:
TypeError: PhpMyAdmin\Export::getFilenameAndMimetype(): Argument #5 ($filenameTemplate) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Controllers\Export\ExportController.php on line 397

Error Occurs When:

in  'Export' -> 'Export method:' select 'Quick - display only the minimal options'
in  'Export' -> 'Export method:' select 'Custom - display all possible options' with 'data' selected gives error

Fixes Tried:

changed the 'max_input_vars' in php.ini values to (2000, 10000, 100000) default value was 1000.
removed all data in table.
tried exporting using mysqldump in terminal
mysqldump -u root -p database_name > ~/Desktop/db.sql

NOTE:

in  'Export' -> 'Export method:' select 'Custom - display all possible options' with 'structure' then export works perfectly

Versions:
Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12
Server version: 10.4.32-MariaDB
PHP version: 8.2.12
Phpmyadmin: Version information: 5.2.1 (up to date)

Expecting an solution for exporting database in phpmyadmin?
Is this an error in phpmyadmin or this error occurs due to my database data or structure?


You might want to file a bug report on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Could you please also let us know which phpMyAdmin version you're using? That's visible on the main home page of the interface.

phpmyadmin Version information: 5.2.1 (up to date)
